# How to uninstall hide.me VPN?

Tags: vpn, macos

I'd like to uninstall Hide.me VPN (e.g. following the instructions on https://www.uninstallmacapp.com/hideme-1-12-removal.html), but I can't seem to get rid of it.

Firstly, I open the 'task manager', but I don't see Hide.me VPN among applications running:

[image]

Then I go to Finder > Applications, right-click on 'hide.me VPN' can choose "Move to trash". However, I get an error message that the program is open:

[image]

How do I 'really' close Hide.me VPN in order to uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still a process from Hide.me running in the background. You need to quit that process first before you can remove the app.

1. Open Activity Monitor (Applications > Utilities)
2. Select All Processes on the drop-down menu at the top of the window.
3. Select the process(es) associated with Hide.me in the list
4. Click Quit Process icon in the left corner of the window
5. Click Quit in the pop-up dialog box (if that doesn’t work, then try Force Quit).